# Why Overflow problem with absolute position

Tags: css, tailwind-css, overflow, jsfiddle, absolute

I want a sidebar with items that when hovered, it show subs items.
I got a problem with overflow and absolute position, pls help me. Thanks!
The detail in this video:
https://youtu.be/4D3hNu2JBvU

Here is the code:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/Go8GAXt5AP

https://jsfiddle.net/coder039/qaz4dp9o/18/

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

Thanks!

Hi! I want a sidebar with items that when hovered, it show subs items.
I got a problem with overflow and absolute position, pls help me. Thanks!

Comment: Please describe what the problem actually is rather than repeat that you have a problem. And put relevant code into your question.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: I think provide jsfiddle link is enough. I also put the video which describe the problem very detail

Comment: You may think a jsfiddle is enough, but that is to misunderstand what SO is trying to achieve. When an external link is removed or debugged your question will be useless for future readers.  As you are not prepared to put code into your question I am afraid it will be closed. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

`overflow-y` due to the position `left` use `top` instead and I applied the best case to show the side bar when hover.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.item {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgb(253, 230, 138);
}

.item.item-with-subitems {
  position: relative;
}
.item.item-with-subitems > span{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.subitems-container {;
  position: absolute;
  right: -70%;
  width: 100px;
  background: #ff0000;
  opacity: 0;
  display:none;
  transform:scale(0.99) translateY(-0.7em);
  transform-origin:top;
  transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.16, 1, 0.3, 1);
  transition-duration:500ms;
  transition-property:opacity,transform;
  list-style: none;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.item.item-with-subitems:hover > .subitems-container {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="item">home</div>
    <div class="item item-with-subitems">
      <span>code</span>
      <ul class="subitems-container">
        <li><a href="#">javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">scheme</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">clojure</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">golang</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item">news</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item item-with-subitems">
      <span>sport</span>
      <ul class="subitems-container">
        <li><a href="#">soccer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">badminton</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">swimming</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want but thanks anyway!

Comment: I changed the code, Now check @WestMountain

Comment: I want the scrollbar of sidebar and the scrollbar of content separated from each other (something like that: https://play.tailwindcss.com/76lheL1woy). But your solution if I want to see the bottom of the sidebar, I must scroll the content too because there are only one scrollbar. But thank you anyway for your time. I found the solution using react-tiny-popover